# How can i find GMT from given date

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a date like 2017-08-12 11:30:00 and i want to display Date as 
`sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am( 06:00 GMT )`  i get `sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am` using following code

```
    let myDate = "2017-08-12 11:30:00"

    let date = myDate.date(format: .custom("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    let strDate = date?.string(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"))
    let localDate = strDate?.date(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"))
    let strLocalDate = localDate?.string(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"))
```

but how can i find GMT ?

for GMT i have also tried `formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"GMT")` but it didn't work.

please help,
Thanks!

Comment: What type is `date`. Please show the code that creates it. In fact, you need to write a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: @JeremyP date format is `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: @JeremyP and what you want to verifiable from me? i have already given a code for my date conversion.

Comment: No. What is the Swift type of the `date` variable? The reason I ask is that you appear to use a format to create it and `Date` in Swift is just a number. It has no format and no timezone. Please read [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you want to convert any date to GMT timezone and display in GMT format  as per your question mentioned or else

Comment: No you have not provided the code for your problem. If I paste it into a Swift playground, I'll get errors because the object `userTeam` is unknown.

Comment: @JeremyP userTeam.date is my variable which provides me date from postman .

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i want to convert any date to GMT timezone

Comment: thats all, show some additional code its better show the sample input and sample OP

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now.

Comment: @KhushbuDesai - if you get `Sat, 12 Aug 2017 11:30:00 AM( GMT )` is this fine or you need exact `sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am( 06:00 GMT )`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i need that `(06:00 GMT )` format because i have already converted date into this format `sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.I have tested, it is working for me in **swift3.0**.

```
        let myDate = "2017-08-12 11:30:00"
        let localDateFormat = DateFormatter()
        localDateFormat.dateFormat = "YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
        let localDate = localDateFormat.date(from: myDate)
        localDateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"
        let myNewDate = localDateFormat.string(from: localDate!)
        print(myNewDate)
        //GMT Date
        let gmtDateFormat = DateFormatter()
        gmtDateFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
        gmtDateFormat.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")! as TimeZone
        let gmtDateString = gmtDateFormater.string(from: localDate!)
        print(gmtDateString)

        print("time:\(myNewDate)(\(gmtDateString))")
```

Comment: @KhushbuDesai - but the OP is get `Thu, 12 Jan 2017 11:30 AM(11:30 AM)`, but you need as `sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am( 06:00 GMT )` how become its correct answer

Comment: set gmtDateFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm", and print("time:\(myNewDate)(\(gmtDateString) GMT)")

Comment: ccan you optimze this `   formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!
       // 2017-08-12 11:30:00
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // "eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
        let date = formatter.date(from: "2017-08-12 11:30:00")
        //sat, 12 aug 2017 11:30 am( 06:00 GMT )
        
         formatter.dateFormat = "eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a( z )"
        let opString = formatter.string(from: date!)
        print(opString)
`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want show time with zone ? If yes, you need to use  `zzz` format. According to the your code please see the code.

```
        let strLocalDate = localDate?.string(format: .custom("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz"))
```

if you have text date then you need to set the timezone as well.

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT");
```

Please let me know about the answer, will give example to set timezone